# Where should I install an outlet for rope lights above a shower?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom, receptacle

I want to put rope lights above my shower because there's a little ledge that they would look perfect on. I just don't know where to put my outlet. Also when I do put my outlet somewhere I'm going to make it controlled by the light switch.

Here is a [YouTube video](https://youtube.com/shorts/Lk2TacB5dKE?feature=share) that explains my question in more detail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to ask your question here, not somewhere else. Rule #1 of the internet: Links die. Once that happens, your question is useless. It's OK to have the link to the video, but please include a drawing, marked up pictures, text description (as a last resort), _something_ to tell us about the question here without making the people who are willing to help you for free jump through unnecessary hoops.

Comment: You put your outlet wherever you can fish cable. I would want it at one end of the run. That's not really a question for the internet, though. Also, I suggest LED strips rather than rope. It'll be almost completely hidden and provide great reflected light. RGB would give you great ambiance.

Comment: For safety sake, check out 12volt light strips.  Multiple types that are driven off a convertor that would stay outside the shower.

Answer (score 3):

### Use low voltage lighting!

Since you want LED strip/rope lights... those are extremely prevalent (and cheap) in the 12 volt DC or 24 volt DC form-factor.

**That crosses off a whole bunch of safety issues**. Simply use  a UL-listed 12 volt or 24 volt power supply, and for bonus points power it from the Load terminals of a GFCI device.

The rules on low voltage wiring are also very relaxed. You can use regular old thermostat cable through tiny holes in the wall, for instance - no need for proper junction boxes.

It's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "outlet" you mean "a receptacle where I can plug in the power to the lights", that is not the best way to do this, particularly in a bathroom.

Bathrooms require GFCI protection for:

- Receptacles, anywhere
- Lights, above a tub or shower, with exceptions for certain types that are designed for wet areas

Lights in a bathroom are generally preferably *not* placed on GFCI, in order to avoid them going out suddenly, particularly if you are holding a hot (hair dryer) or sharp (electric shaver) item that caused the GFCI to trip. But in your case, you probably can't avoid the GFCI requirement because you want the lights above the shower itself.

In addition, a receptacle should *never* be placed really close to water and steam (e.g., above a shower), simply because it will wear out faster and lead to nuisance GFCI trips (until the whole thing just dies).

A switch-controlled light generally does not have to use a separate receptacle, plug and cord to connect a device. In fact, doing so for permanently installed devices simply adds extra points of failure and unnecessary exposed wires.

If you are installing 120V AC lights then I highly recommend a fully hardwired setup:

- GFCI/breaker for the circuit or (preferred and usually lower cost, particularly if the receptacle will be used for other stuff) GFCI/receptacle
- Power from the circuit (GFCI/breaker) or the *load* side of the GFCI/receptacle goes to the switch
- Power goes from the switch to the lights

The only exposed receptacle, if any, is near the switch, not in or above the shower. You can even use an existing bathroom receptacle protected by GFCI to feed these lights (you can't feed lights in other rooms from a bathroom receptacle circuit, but you can feed lights in the bathroom from that circuit) if there is a receptacle near the new switch location or if it is useless to put a receptacle next to the new switch.

However, if you are installing low-voltage lights then you need to either:

- Use a switch-controlled receptacle (GFCI protection either prior to the switch, as above, or at the receptacle itself), a plug-in power pack, and route the wiring along the walls to the lights. You *may* be able to run the wiring *inside* the walls, but while the rules are relaxed compared to 120V wiring, you still have to have wires that are designed for in-wall use.
- Use a switch-controlled in-wall power pack and in-wall wiring to the lights. This gets a bit more complex, but results in a clean finished appearance similar to 120V hardwired light fixtures. The actual power pack will need to be chosen properly - it must be designed to fit inside a junction box or on the surface of a junction box (like a doorbell transformer), and you will use regular in-wall wiring (e.g., NM cable, a.k.a., Romex). However, since it is low-voltage you *may* be exempt from the GFCI requirement for wet area lighting. I am not sure about the GFCI requirement, hopefully a code guru will clarify that.

Comment: Rope lights over a shower - low voltage would be the only way I'd even contemplate that.